# SAP NetWeaver Application Server ABAP 7.03 trial error after installation

Tags: abap, sap-basis

I am new to SAP. I have installed SAP NetWeaver Application Server ABAP 7.03 trial on Windows 7, 64 bit professional. When I started the server in SAP management console it became briefly green and later within a minute it turns yellow again. Could you please let me know how I can solve this problem? Here with pasting `dev_w0` for your reference.

```
---------------------------------------------------
trc file: "dev_w0", trc level: 1, release: "720"
---------------------------------------------------
*
*  ACTIVE TRACE LEVEL           1
*  ACTIVE TRACE COMPONENTS      all, MJ
*
M sysno      00
M sid        NSP
M systemid   562 (PC with Windows NT)
M relno      7200
M patchlevel 0
M patchno    201
M intno      20020600
M make       multithreaded, Unicode, 64 bit, optimized
M profile    \\SAP\sapmnt\NSP\SYS\profile\NSP_DVEBMGS00_SAP
M pid        2520
M
M  kernel runs with dp version 133000(ext=118000) (@(#) DPLIB-INT-VERSION-133000-UC)
M  length of sys_adm_ext is 588 bytes
M  ***LOG Q0Q=> tskh_init, WPStart (Workp. 0 2520) [dpxxdisp.c   1377]
I  MtxInit: 30000 0 0
M  DpSysAdmExtCreate: ABAP is active
M  DpSysAdmExtCreate: VMC (JAVA VM in WP) is not active
M 
M Mon Jul 15 12:14:49 2013
M  DpIPCInit2: read dp-profile-values from sys_adm_ext
M  DpShMCreate: sizeof(wp_adm)        31696    (2264)
M  DpShMCreate: sizeof(tm_adm)        5517056    (27448)
M  DpShMCreate: sizeof(wp_ca_adm)        64000    (64)
M  DpShMCreate: sizeof(appc_ca_adm)    64000    (64)
M  DpCommTableSize: max/headSize/ftSize/tableSize=500/16/584064/584080
M  DpShMCreate: sizeof(comm_adm)        584080    (1144)
M  DpSlockTableSize: max/headSize/ftSize/fiSize/tableSize=0/0/0/0/0
M  DpShMCreate: sizeof(slock_adm)        0    (296)
M  DpFileTableSize: max/headSize/ftSize/tableSize=0/0/0/0
M  DpShMCreate: sizeof(file_adm)        0    (80)
M  DpShMCreate: sizeof(vmc_adm)        0    (2152)
M  DpShMCreate: sizeof(wall_adm)        (41664/42896/64/192)
M  DpShMCreate: sizeof(gw_adm)    48
M  DpShMCreate: sizeof(j2ee_adm)    3952
M  DpShMCreate: SHM_DP_ADM_KEY        (addr: 000000000FC10050, size: 6363600)
M  DpShMCreate: allocated sys_adm at 000000000FC10060
M  DpShMCreate: allocated wp_adm_list at 000000000FC13070
M  DpShMCreate: allocated wp_adm at 000000000FC13260
M  DpShMCreate: allocated tm_adm_list at 000000000FC1AE40
M  DpShMCreate: allocated tm_adm at 000000000FC1AE90
M  DpShMCreate: allocated wp_ca_adm at 000000001015DDA0
M  DpShMCreate: allocated appc_ca_adm at 000000001016D7B0
M  DpShMCreate: allocated comm_adm at 000000001017D1C0
M  DpShMCreate: system runs without slock table
M  DpShMCreate: system runs without file table
M  DpShMCreate: allocated vmc_adm_list at 000000001020BB60
M  DpShMCreate: system runs without vmc_adm
M  DpShMCreate: allocated gw_adm at 000000001020BC10
M  DpShMCreate: allocated j2ee_adm at 000000001020BC50
M  DpShMCreate: allocated ca_info at 000000001020CBD0
M  DpShMCreate: allocated wall_adm at 000000001020CC60
M  DpCommAttachTable: attached comm table (header=000000001017D1C0/ft=000000001017D1D0)
M 
M Mon Jul 15 12:14:50 2013
M  DpRqQInit: use protect_queue / slots_per_queue 0 / 2001 from sys_adm
M  rdisp/queue_size_check_value :  -> on,50,30,40,500,50,500,80
X  EmInit: MmSetImplementation( 2 ).
X  MM global diagnostic options set: 0
X  <ES> client 0 initializing ....
X  <ES> EsILock: use spinlock for locking
X  Using implementation view
X  <EsNT> Using memory model view.
M  <EsNT> Memory Reset disabled as NT default
X  ES initialized.
X 
X Mon Jul 15 12:14:51 2013
X  mm.dump: set maximum dump mem to 96 MB
M  DpVmcSetActive: set vmc state DP_VMC_NOT_ACTIVE
M  ThStart: taskhandler started
M  ThInit: initializing DIA work process W0
M 
M Mon Jul 15 12:14:57 2013
M  ThInit: running on host SAP
M  calling db_connect ...
B  Loading DB library 'C:\usr\sap\NSP\DVEBMGS00\exe\dbsdbslib.dll' ...
B  Library 'C:\usr\sap\NSP\DVEBMGS00\exe\dbsdbslib.dll' loaded
B  Version of 'C:\usr\sap\NSP\DVEBMGS00\exe\dbsdbslib.dll' is "720.00", patchlevel (0.201)
C 
C Mon Jul 15 12:14:58 2013
C 
C  DBSDBSLIB : version 720.00, patch 0.201 (Make PL 0.201)
C  MAXDB shared library (dbsdbslib) patchlevels (last 10)
C    (0.201) Take care of warnings during database connect (note 1600066)
C    (0.117) Define a primary key on the temp tables for R3szchk (note 1606260)
C    (0.114) Support of MaxDB 7.8 and 7.9 (note 1653058)
C    (0.103) Close all lob locators at end of the transaction (note 1626591)
C    (0.101) Fix for unknown table __TABLE_SIZES_ (R3szchk) (note 1619504)
C    (0.098) Use filesystem counter for R3szchk (note 1606260)
C    (0.092) Secondary connection to HANA (note 1481256)
C    (0.089) UPDSTAT with SAPSYSTEMNAME longer as 3 characters (note 1584921)
C    (0.081) No UPSERT on WBCROSSGT (note 1521468)
C    (0.080) New feature batch streaming (note 1340617)
C 
C 
C  Loading SQLDBC client runtime ...
C 
C Mon Jul 15 12:14:59 2013
C  SQLDBC Module  : C:\sapdb\clients\NSP\pgm\libSQLDBC77.dll
C  SQLDBC SDK     : SQLDBC.H  7.9.7    BUILD 010-123-243-190
C  SQLDBC Runtime : libSQLDBC 7.9.7    BUILD 010-123-243-190
C  SQLDBC client runtime is MaxDB 7.9.7.010 CL 243190
C  SQLDBC supports new DECIMAL interface : 1
C  SQLDBC supports VARIABLE INPUT data   : 1
C  SQLDBC supports VARIABLE OUTPUT data  : 1
C  SQLDBC supports Multiple Streams      : 1
C  SQLDBC supports LOB LOCATOR KEEPALIVE : 1
C  SQLDBC supports LOB LOCATOR COPY      : 1
C  SQLDBC supports BULK SELECT with LOBS : 1
C  SQLDBC supports BATCH STREAM          : 1
C  INFO : SQLOPT= -I 0 -t 0 -S SAPR3
C  Try to connect (DEFAULT) on connection 0 ...
C  *** ERROR => Connect to database failed, rc = -10709 (Connection failed (RTE:[5] database not running))
[dbsdbsql.cpp 139]
B  ***LOG BV3=> severe db error -10709    ; work process is stopped [dbsh         1241]
B  ***LOG BY2=> sql error -10709 performing CON [dblink       544]
B  ***LOG BY0=> Connection failed (RTE:[5] database not running) [dblink       544]
M  ***LOG R19=> ThInit, db_connect ( DB-Connect 000256) [thxxhead.c   1490]
M  in_ThErrHandle: 1
M  *** ERROR => ThInit: db_connect (step 1, th_errno 13, action 3, level 1) [thxxhead.c   11321]
M 
M  Info for wp 0
M 
M    pid = 2520
M    severity = 0
M    status = 0
M    stat = WP_NEW
M    waiting_for = NO_WAITING
M    reqtype = DP_RQ_DIAWP
M    act_reqtype = NO_REQTYPE
M    req.req_info =
M    req.tid = -1
M    req.uid = 4294967295
M    req.mode = 255
M    req.len = 0
M    req.rq_id = 65535
M    req.rq_source =
M    last_tid = 0
M    last_uid = 0
M    last_mode = 0
M    act_cs_count = 0
M    csTrack = 0
M    csTrackRwExcl = 0
M    csTrackRwShrd = 0
M    mode_cleaned_counter = 0
M    control_flag = 0
M    int_checked_resource(RFC) = 0
M    ext_checked_resource(RFC) = 0
M    int_checked_resource(HTTP) = 0
M    ext_checked_resource(HTTP) = 0
M    report = >                                        <
M    action = 0
M    tab_name = >                              <
M    attachedVm = no VM
M 
M  ThIErrHandle: current request:
M 
M  -IN-- sender_id ?                 tid  -1    wp_ca_blk   -1      wp_id -1
M  -IN-- action    -                 uid  -1    appc_ca_blk -1      type  -   
M  -IN-- new_stat  NO_CHANGE         mode 255   len         0       rq_id -1
M 
M  *****************************************************************************
M  *
M  *  LOCATION    SAP-Server SAP_NSP_00 on host SAP (wp 0)
M  *  ERROR       ThInit: db_connect
M  *
M  *  TIME        Mon Jul 15 12:14:59 2013
M  *  RELEASE     720
M  *  COMPONENT   Taskhandler
M  *  VERSION     1
M  *  RC          13
M  *  MODULE      thxxhead.c
M  *  LINE        11602
M  *  COUNTER     1
M  *
M  *****************************************************************************
M 
M  PfStatDisconnect: disconnect statistics
M  Entering TH_CALLHOOKS
M  ThCallHooks: call hook >ThrBtcCallLgCl< for event BEFORE_DUMP
M  ThCallHooks: hook >ThrBtcCallLgCl< o.k.
M  ThCallHooks: call hook >ThrSaveSPAFields< for event BEFORE_DUMP
M  *** ERROR => ThrSaveSPAFields: no valid thr_wpadm [thxxrun1.c   844]
M  *** ERROR => ThCallHooks: event handler ThrSaveSPAFields for event BEFORE_DUMP failed [thxxtool3.c  303]
M  ThIErrHandle: entering ThSetStatError
M  ThIErrHandle: do not call ThrCoreInfo (no_core_info=0, in_dynp_env=0)
M  Entering ThReadDetachMode
M  call ThrShutDown (1)...
M  ***LOG Q02=> wp_halt, WPStop (Workp. 0 2520) [dpnttool.c   339]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The database has some issue which you must investigate. From the trace you quoted I see that you are using MAXDB. If possible try to install SAP MaxDB Database Studio. You can download it from the SAP Marketplace. There seems to be also a community edition I have not tried:
http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/scn/maxdb-downloads

Start DB Studio and connect to your NSP database. You will presumably need the master password specified during installation. Check out what errors you can find in the trace.

Alternatively you can try to use command line tools: dbmcli should be available for user nspadm. To login try something like this: `dbmcli -d NSP -u control,<password>`

The command `help` is your friend. Start with something like this: `db_state -v`

If the database is healthy check connectivity. A simple check which shows if the database is available to SAP: `R3trans -d`

If the return code is (0000) all is good. Otherwise check out the file created by R3trans: trans.log

If the database worked some time after installation but then suddenly ceased to operate the log area might simply be full. Either extend it then or switch to OVERWRITE.